# How to access a variable across two files

Tags: php, global-variables, static-variables, file-access

I have three files - `global.php,` `test.php`, `test1.php`

Global.php

```
$filename;
$filename = "test";
```

test.php

```
$filename = "myfile.jpg";
echo $filename;
```

test1.php

`echo $filename;`

I can read this variable from both test and test1 files by 
`include 'global.php';`

Now i want to set the value of `$filename` in `test.php` and the same value i want to read in `test1.php.`

I tried with session variables as well but due to two different files i am not able to capture the variable.

How to achieve this........

Thanks for help in advance.....

Comment: Could you show us some code? IMO, there's no reason for this not to work. Also keep in mind that variables are temporary at each reloading of the page will require all the variables to be recreated.

Comment: i have added code for all three files.

Comment: Where is your session?

Answer (score 12):

Use:

global.php

```
<?php
if(!session_id()) session_start();
$filename = "test";
if(!isset($_SESSION['filename'])) {
    $_SESSION['filename'] = $filename;
}
?>
```

test.php

```
<?php
if(!session_id()) session_start();
//include("global.php");
$_SESSION['filename'] = "new value";
?>
```

test1.php

```
<?php
if(!session_id()) session_start();
$filename = $_SESSION['filename'];
echo $filename; //output new value
?>
```

Comment: Is the include necessary to set the variable name in `test.php`?

Comment: Thanks @LouieBertoncin , Good findings. No need to include `global.php` in `test.php`

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to understand this is as following:
You have one file *index.php* whit some variable defined.

```
$indexVar = 'sometext';
```

This variable is visible on all *index.php* file. But like a function, if you include other files, the variable will not be visible unless you specify that this variable has scope global.

You should redefine the scope of this variable in your new file, like this:

```
global $indexVar;
```

Then you will be able to acess directly by calling it as you were in your main file. You could use an "echo" in both files, *index.php* and any other file.

Answer (score 2):

First you start session at the top of the page.

Assign your variable into your session.

Check this and Try it your self

test.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // session start
include("global.php");
$filename = "myfile.jpg";
$_SESSION['samplename']=$filename ; // Session Set
?>
```

test1.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // session start
$getvalue = $_SESSION['samplename']; // session get
echo $getvalue;
?>
```

Comment: after assigning value to $filename i am closing test.php file.
so session is not persisting

Comment: @user2688512  include function use after session_start