# Access variable from one PHP file in another

Tags: php

I have a variable called $name in my atlas.php file. I then have another php file called display.php where I want to print out the value of $name what was established in the other file.

The research I did led me to include, but when I do

```
include 'atlas.php';
```

in my display.php file, it displays all of the work that is inside of atlas.php. I simply want access to the variable, how would I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP, getting variable from another php-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135131/php-getting-variable-from-another-php-file)

Comment: check [How to access a variable across two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588972/how-to-access-a-variable-across-two-files)

Comment: @LucasArbex This is still confusing me as to why it is displaying all of the stuff from atlas.php when I do include

Comment: @KaitlynWheeler take a look at the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). It has an extensible explanation about the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider I have one Php file that sets a var and has the side effect of echoing out that variable.

```
<?php

$greeting = "hello earth";
echo $greeting;
```

Let's call that file greeting.php.

In another file, I could use a function to restrict scope. I could suppress output, and return the contents of the desired variable.

```
<?php
function get_greeting() {
    ob_start();
    include_once 'greeting.php';
    ob_end_clean();

    return $greeting;
}

$greeting = get_greeting();
var_dump($greeting);
```

This will output:

```
string(11) "hello earth"
```

However, I don't think I've ever used anything like it practically, but that's not to say there is never a need.  Be wary of other possible side effects.